# Open cover of a set of real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

Using the definition of the open cover, I can prove that if a function is bounded on any open set $(x-\delta(x),x+\delta(x)), x \in [a,b]$, then that function is also bounded on $[a,b]$. Using the contrapositive, we would come to the conclusion that if a function is not bounded on $[a,b]$, then it would not be  bounded on any open set $(x-\delta(x),x+\delta(x)), x \in [a,b]$. This doesn't seem to make sense for me, can someone please clarify or help me understand how this is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contrapositive is not what you stated but instead

> if a function is not bounded on $[a,b]$, then there exists an open set $(x-\delta(x),x+\delta(x)), x \in [a,b]$ where the function is not bounded

Comment: ok i see... thank you!